# VBA Need to limit the amount of times a random selection gets picked to x amount of times

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up Job assignments for my 11 employees randomly from 8 tasks daily. Out of the 8 tasks, one needs to be selected 4 times, one needs to be selected 2 times and the other six tasks need only be selected once. Since there are only 8 tasks and 11 employees, some of the six single selected tasks can be selected twice. I have been trying to use a weighted system and it works "ok" but I feel there should be a way to do what I want while still using the weighted system (maybe not), I just can not figure out how to set the limit of each randomly selected item. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried For loops, Case, and IF/Then, but can not get anything to work. The code I have listed currently works to make the random selections but sometimes gets into having too many or too little of one item or more.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RandomName As String
Dim Row As Long
Dim R As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim upperBound As Integer
Dim lowerBound As Integer

'RandomName = Range("I2").value
Set R = Range("I2:I12")

'upperBound = 20
'lowerBound = 5

'RandomName = WeightedRnd(Array("Lamination", "Metro", "Final Insp", "AGL", "iEcho", "LPN", "Confocal", "Hardness"), Array(20, 18, 20, 8, 8, 10, 5, 11))

For Each cell In R
cell.value = WeightedRnd(Array("Lamination", "Metro", "Final Insp", "AGL", "iEcho", "LPN", "Confocal", "Hardness"), Array(25, 17, 19, 7, 8, 9, 5, 10))

'    If RandomName Like "*Lamination*" = 4 Then
'        cell.value = WeightedRnd(Array("Metro", "Final Insp", "AGL", "iEcho", "LPN", "Confocal", "Hardness"), Array(25, 25, 10, 10, 10, 5, 15))
    'cell.value = RandomName 'Int((upperBound - lowerBound + 1) * Rnd + lowerBound)
'    End If
'Worksheets("Crew").Cells(Row, 1).value = RandomName
Next cell
'Range("I2", Row + 1, 11).value = RandomName
End Sub

Function WeightedRnd(items As Variant, weights As Variant) As Variant
Dim myItems(1 To 100) As Variant
Dim weight As Variant
Dim item As Variant
Dim myNumber As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim pick As Integer

i = 1
n = 0

For Each weight In weights
    For p = 1 To weight
       myItems(i) = items(n)
       i = i + 1
    Next
    n = n + 1
Next

n = UBound(myItems) - LBound(myItems) + 1
pick = getRandom(1, n)
WeightedRnd = myItems(pick)
End Function

Function getRandom(lowerBound, upperBound)
Randomize
getRandom = Int((upperBound - lowerBound + 1) * Rnd + lowerBound)
End Function
```

Comment: Hint: putting criteria around a random selection means that it is not random ….

Comment: I understand what you're saying here, but what this is intended to do, is randomly pick the tasks for any given Associate. My end goal is to have this randomly assign the tasks for each person then copy the data to a calendar so the Associates can just come in to work and see what they are doing for the day. Plus this gives them the opportunity to know what they will be doing for whole work week and keep the tasks random so they don't get burnt out do the same job all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of considering 8 tasks in a list, consider 12 tasks (of which some are duplicates). Depending on your needs, you may want to consider two lists - the first 6 are the two duplicated tasks, and then the remaining 6 are the singular tasks. How you split this up depends on your limits and criteria.

Now, you can randomly select from the lists (removing an item from the list once selected) and meet your limits/criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone taking a look and trying to help. As AJD pointed out, try a different route to get what I want, so that's what I did and found the answer I needed at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-coding-help-random-selection-from-list-without/f281278d-1acc-47c0-8f1b-7054bd6d538a.

Code here:

```
Sub RangeRandomize()
 Dim SrcRange As Range, FillRange As Range
 Dim c As Range, r As Long
 Set SrcRange = Application.InputBox("Select source names", Type:=8)
 Set FillRange = Application.InputBox("Select Fill range", Type:=8)
 If FillRange.Cells.Count > SrcRange.Cells.Count Then
 MsgBox "Fill range too large"
 Exit Sub
 End If
 r = SrcRange.Cells.Count
 For Each c In FillRange
 Do
 c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(SrcRange, Int((r * Rnd) + 1))
 Loop Until WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FillRange, c.Value) < 2
 Next
 End Sub
```

Changing the SrcRange  and FillRange to specific ranges and adding a clear contents line is giving me what I need.

Thank all!